# If $X \sim \operatorname{NegBinom}(r,p)$ and $Y|(X = k) \sim \operatorname{Binom}(k,\beta)$ what is the distribution of $Y$?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am trying to figure the distribution for randomly observing only certain events where the number of all events is Poisson or Negative binomial distributed. I know (and can prove myself) that if

$X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda) $ and $Y|(X = k) \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(k,\beta)$

then $Y \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\beta\lambda)$.

But I cannot find the unconditional distribution for $Y$ when $X \sim \operatorname{NegativeBinomial}(r,p)$

My attempt at figuring the negative binomial case is below:

$$P(X = m, Y = n | \beta, r, p) = {{m+r-1}\choose{m}}(1-p)^r\beta^n(1-\beta)^{m-n}{m\choose{n}}$$

Giving the unconditional distribution as
$$P(Y = n | \beta, r, p) = \sum_{m = n}^{\infty}{{m+r-1}\choose{m}}(1-p)^r\beta^n(1-\beta)^{m-n}{m\choose{n}} = 
\\ = (1-p)^r\beta^n{1\over{n!(r-1)!}}\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}{p^m(1-\beta)^{m-n} {{(m+r-1)!}\over{(m-n)!}}} = \\
= (1-p)^r\beta^n{1\over{n!(r-1)!}}p^n\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{{(p(1-\beta))^{i}\over{i!}}{(i+n+r-1)!}}
$$

But I cannot figure out how to evaluate the last infinite sum due to the $(i+n+r-1)!$ term. Thanks for any hints.

**EDIT:** Since negative binomial can be treated as a sum of geometric distributions, it should be sufficient to handle the case of $r=1$, but even this simplification does not let me to make any progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the identity
$$ \binom{m + r - 1}{m} \binom{m}{n} = \frac{1}{(r - 1)!n!} \frac{(m + r - 1)!}{(m - n)!} = \binom{n + r - 1}{n} \binom{m + r - 1}{m - n}, $$

it follows that
\begin{align}
&\sum_{m = n}^{\infty}{{m+r-1}\choose{m}}(1-p)^r\color{red}{p^m} \beta^n(1-\beta)^{m-n}{m\choose{n}} \\
&= \binom{n + r - 1}{n} \frac{(1-p)^r\beta^n p^n}{(1-p+p\beta)^{r+n}}\sum_{m = n}^\infty \binom{m + r - 1}{m - n} (1 - p + p\beta)^{r + n} (1 - \beta)^{m - n}p^{m - n}  \\
&= \binom{n + r - 1}{n} \frac{(1-p)^r\beta^n p^n}{(1-p+p\beta)^{r+n}}.
\end{align}

The summand in line 2 is the pmf of a negative binomial variable, which is why the sum is $1$. Notice also that you forgot a $\color{red}{p^m}$.

This is a negative binomial distribution with parameters $r$ and $\frac{p \beta}{1 - p + p\beta}$.